# KL-Divergence between approximate and true posteriors with 2 latent causes

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian, bayes-theorem, bayesian-network

Assume I have a directed latent-variable model where $y\in \mathbb{R} \to x$ **and** $z \in \mathbb{R}^k \to x$. Something like the following:

                   `y z
                   | |
                    v
                    x`

Can I compute the KL-divergence between an approximate posterior $Q(z,y|x)$ and true $P(z,y|x)$ as follows?

$$
KL(Q(z,y|x)||P(z,y|x)) = \mathbb{E}_{y\sim Q}\big[
\mathbb{E}_{z\sim Q}\big[log Q(z,y|x) - log P(z,y|x) \big]
\big]
= \mathbb{E}_{y\sim Q}\big[
\mathbb{E}_{z\sim Q}\big[log Q(z,y|x) - log P(x|z,y) -log  P(y) - log P(z) + log P(x)\big]
\big] \\
$$

Here, I used the relation 
$$
p(z,y|x) = \frac{p(x,y,z)}{p(x)} = \frac{p(x|z,y)p(z)p(y)}{p(x)}
$$

Afterwards, with $p(y)=p(y|x)p(x)$,
$$
KL(Q(z,y|x)||P(z,y|x)) = \mathbb{E}_{y\sim Q}\big[
\mathbb{E}_{z\sim Q}\big[log Q(z,y|x) - log P(x|z,y) -log  P(y|x) - log P(z)\big]
\big] \\
$$

Now, because of independence $Q(y,z|x)=Q(y|x)Q(z|x)$, so
$$KL(Q(z,y|x)||P(z,y|x)) = \mathbb{E}_{y\sim Q}\big[\mathbb{E}_{z\sim Q}\big[log Q(z|x) - log P(x|z,y) -log P(z)\big]\big] + \mathbb{E}_{y\sim Q}\big[ log Q(y|x) - log P(y|x)
\big] \\
$$

Finally, removing probabilities from expectations if they don't depend on the conditioning variable,
$$
KL(Q(z,y|x)||P(z,y|x)) = \mathbb{E}_{y\sim Q}\big[\mathbb{E}_{z\sim Q}\big[- log P(x|z,y) \big]\big] + \mathbb{E}_{y\sim Q}\big[ log Q(y|x) - log P(y|x)
\big] + \mathbb{E}_{z\sim Q}\big[ log Q(z|x) -log P(z) \big] \\
$$
Can I finally conclude that
$$
KL(Q(z,y|x)||P(z,y|x)) = - \mathbb{E}_{y\sim Q}\big[\mathbb{E}_{z\sim Q}\big[log P(x|z,y) \big]\big] + KL \big( log Q(y|x) || log P(y|x)
\big) + KL\big( log Q(z|x) || log P(z) \big) \text{?}
$$